# Server denies Authorization header and unable to authenticate with laravel passport in live server

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I have an issue with Laravel API authentication:
When I send request in localhost it successfully verifies Bearer token and I can access user data but in live server it will returns an exception and gives

> "Unauthenticated" error message.

I have found that the server filters the Authorization header and when I dump the request headers in live server it doesn't have Bearer token (in localhost it has). I have changed the

> .htaccess file

several times due to previous questions in gitHub and here but it didn't help. So can anyone tell me what must I do?

Comment: you said: server doesn't have Bearer token, this token you sent, how you send it?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy I have sent it via header. The request has two headers: **Authorization** and **content-type**. After sending request when i dump headers it doesn't have this two headers(in localhost it has).